# Can you discard the plot for a better character arc?

Tags: creative-writing, plot

I think I failed to communicate my intentions in the [previous](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/48586/dumping-an-entire-world-for-dramatic-effect) question.

I was always fascinated by JoJo's Bizzare Adventure, and to an extent Araki's writing style. The main power system (Stands) of JoJo is very loose and quite a few of them (Bohemian Rhapsody, Bastet, Osiris, Atum) were obviously there for the sake of a nice/interesting idea.

They were incredibly conditional powers and always changed up the rules in ways no other stand did. Atum had to be beaten in a videogame, Bohemian Rhapsody was more of a phenomena/catastrophe than an actual power, Chariot Requiem simply switched up people's bodies to make things more confusing, and it worked.

I always aimed for something similar with Anon. Anon's overpoweredness always rubs off as a (usually impossible) change in the world around the characters and how they adapt to them. I can't hope but feel that this artificial plot has the ability to serve a certain story, that is above and beyond the plot, better.

For example: If the story focused on pirates (the Sir Francis Drake types, not the *other*) and sea battles, Anon would show up with a 1.2 km long, 180 meters wide, unsinkable aircraft carrier with 200 UAVs ready to go. He doesn't actually kill anyone, instead, he toys with them and creates "obstacle courses" the characters have to get through or they'll die.

More precisely it's good for poetic justice and/or giving place for interesting (and usually impossible) situations for the characters that would help develop them. But the characters are still rooted in the original plot, so I can't cut that out.

**How can I abandon the original plot without making the readers feel alienated?**

Comment: I assume "the previous question" is [this one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/48586/23927)? It would be better if you linked to it, to help provide context.

Comment: @F1Krazy I made hole, and now you want to bury me in it, don't you?

Comment: No, it's just that if you're asking a new question based on an old one, it always helps to link to the old one just so people people understand why you're asking what you're asking. (I didn't downvote btw, this question seems fine to me.)

Comment: @Mephistopheles If you're going to provide examples to help illustrate your point, can you explain *how* those examples illustrate your point? Or just make the point in more detail without using those examples. You shouldn't assume people read what you read, especially if it's niche. Imagine if I said, "I want to capture the feeling of personal risk that Orlando had in making modified bridger clones that may have no place in the universe, just to contact the Transmuters". If you haven't read Greg Egan's *Diaspora*, you may have no idea what I just said. And I can't fault you for that.

Comment: I think, and I am not certain because your question is a bit unclear to me (see Bridgeburners' comment above), that you are actually thinking about a similar problem to one that I have been dealing with in my narrative for some time. Are you basically looking at a setting change in which most of the previous characters and places are lost?

Comment: @ArkensteinXII Wait, I have an idea.

Comment: For reference, this is a question I asked trying to tackle the issue I am having: [Abandoning the Ordinary World](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44651/abandoning-the-ordinary-world)

Comment: @Amadeus Listen, it has already been done. The first answer says so. I'm not abandoning the characters or their backstory. I'm abandoning the original course of the plot.

Comment: @Mephistopheles No, it has not been done, Archer doesn't abandon the plot. Every episode has a plot, every season has a plot, and they do not get abandoned. They may switch the premise, but they do not abandon the plot in the middle of it. I've watched Archer, like other series every episode (or sometimes multi-episode arc) works as a story. What's changing each season is the **premise** or **setting**, but even then a semi-plausible excuse is given: Archer is delusional, or the crew gets framed, or whatever. And it's a comedy, so some ludicrous can work, but **still** no plots are abandoned.

Comment: @Amadeus Okay, fine. Then explain The Red Wedding.

Comment: @Mephistopheles What's to explain? It was the plot, there was a betrayal of a promise and revenge was taken. That did not come out of the blue, the Red Wedding may have been a surprise, but it makes sense in retrospect, all the motives and necessary cruelty were there. What you are talking about is just your inability to finish a story so you come up with a deus ex machina to end the plot completely.

Comment: @Amadeus "end the plot completely." Where did you get that from? The plot doesn't end it has merely changed direction.

Comment: @Mephistopheles "End the plot completely" comes from the title of your question, where you are asking about "discarding the plot". I suspect that in actual fact what you want to do is to discard the setting, not the plot.

Comment: You say "discard the plot", and "abandon the original plot", that is ending it. It makes no difference if you start up a new plot, you still alienate the reader, they expect the original plot to have a satisfying ending and you are denying them that experience. That *might* be okay if you haven't spent more than a few pages on it, they haven't invested any mental energy in it. But even then, they'd expect something organic that makes sense in retrospect, and your bizarre and senseless switch-up does not. A strategy planning session interrupted by bad guys can make sense, your ideas do not.

Comment: @Amadeus Just because a question is a bad idea doesn't make it off-topic or unclear. If you dislike the premise, downvote and move on. Continued arguments in the comments aren't helping anyone.

Comment: I've VTC as "unclear" because the only interpretation of this I can make is that it's essentially the same as the previous two. If it's supposed to be a *different* question then that's not clear. The previous question in particular got 7 answers, including some very good advice. Unless you can better articulate either a) why this question is different or b) why the previous advice you've received doesn't work I don't think you're going to get anywhere.

Comment: @linksassin It is not exactly an argument in the comments, it is a conversation because I can't in good conscience write an answer, and the OP deserves to know why I am voting to close. I would have left it as my only comment, but the OP has serious misunderstandings about writing fiction, and I am in fact trying to educate a stubborn student. It may be true the comments aren't helping anyone, some students are closed-minded, think they know it all, and cannot be helped. But the intent is to make the OP a better writer.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems like you want to do something similar to Archer has had going on for the past couple of seasons.

To whit, the show is a work comedy set in a spy agency.  Around season four, the writers felt they had milked the spy genre for all it's worth, and introduced season five with the cast now having to make it into the world of drug trafficking (for reasons).  They then realized that what fans loved about the show wasn't the premise but the characters and their quirks and foibles and after another season returning to the spy genre, they began doing a genre shift premise for each season.   Season 7 had the gang start a detective agency (and moved the New York base to L.A.) and conclude with the lead character entering a coma which allowed the writers to go all in in the genre shift all framed as the coma charater's dreams while he is struggling for conciousness.   Season 8 was post-WWII era Noir detective series (also in L.A. but contrasting with the more realistic PI set up of season six) and re-imagined all the characters into archetypes in the Noir setting (the main rival was now a dirty cop, the mad scientist who had some uncomfortable Nazi lineages was set up to be an actual Nazi Mad Scientist... but the pay off to his scheme to help the Germans was probably insanely awesome).  Season 8 re-imagined the gang into a pre-World War II pulp adventure set in French Polyneasia and found the gang searching for lost native treasure.  Season 10 re-imagined the gang into a Space Opera setting.

Each change keeps core elements of the characters and their basic personality, but also with some elements that are clearly inspired by the lead's opinion of the character (in the real world, the rival/crooked cop is a by the books meek character compared to Archer's cowboy personality... Archer has elevated him to villainy in both seasons) while the real characters of Krieger, Pam, and Lana tend to hold similar roles to Archer (the best gal friend who busts his chops, the wacky but reliably friendly ally, and the attractive girl who hates his guts).

This works because the roles are so established, that the character interactions can easily be sussed out no matter what the setting.   The cast are largely unchanged, it's the setting and the jokes that get an update.